# What does the notation $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$ mean?

Tags: derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

Suppose **G**$(u,v) = (x, y, z)$

In terms of derivatives, what does $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$ mean?

Comment: This is a notation that resembles that for the [jacobian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). I would guess $\frac{\delta(x,y)}{\delta(u,v)}$ is mean to be the matrix (or the determinant of the matrix) with elements $a_{ij} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_j}$ where $x_1 = x,x_2=y,u_1=u,u_2=v$.

Comment: Yes! Sorry about the typo, I'm not very good with TeX @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \det\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} \\[4pt] \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{bmatrix}.
$$
This expression is called the Jacobian of the function by which $(x,y)$ depends on $(u,v)$.

There is an identity
$$
\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \, du\,dv = dx\,dy,
$$
used for transforming an integral in the $(x,y)$-plane to an integral in the $(u,v)$-plane when $x$, $y$ are given functions of $u,v$.  Sometimes this makes the integral tractable. (In cases where the Jacobian is negative and one is integrating with respect to area but not with respect to *oriented* area, one takes the absolute value of the Jacobian.)